# Find Difference of Dates between certain fields in powershell

Tags: powershell

i have the below PS custom object

```
Time                  DateFormat Event Type
----                  ---------- ----------
3/31/2020 11:59:35 PM 31/03/2020 AGENT_RECONNECTED
3/31/2020 4:01:56 PM  31/03/2020 AGENT_DISCONNECTED
3/31/2020 4:14:19 PM  31/03/2020 AGENT_CONNECTED
3/31/2020 4:24:12 PM  31/03/2020 AGENT_CONNECTED
3/31/2020 4:30:31 PM  31/03/2020 AGENT_DISCONNECTED
3/31/2020 4:36:08 PM  31/03/2020 AGENT_RECONNECTED
3/31/2020 5:12:49 PM  31/03/2020 AGENT_DISCONNECTED
3/31/2020 6:25:39 PM  31/03/2020 AGENT_RECONNECTED
3/31/2020 7:09:08 PM  31/03/2020 AGENT_DISCONNECTED
3/31/2020 7:38:53 PM  31/03/2020 AGENT_RECONNECTED
3/31/2020 7:44:44 PM  31/03/2020 AGENT_CONNECTED
3/31/2020 8:23:48 PM  31/03/2020 AGENT_DISCONNECTED
3/31/2020 9:33:36 PM  31/03/2020 AGENT_RECONNECTED
3/31/2020 9:35:58 PM  31/03/2020 AGENT_DISCONNECTED
3/31/2020 10:46:54 PM 31/03/2020 AGENT_RECONNECTED
3/31/2020 10:50:54 PM 31/03/2020 AGENT_DISCONNECTED
3/31/2020 10:53:10 PM 31/03/2020 AGENT_RECONNECTED
3/31/2020 11:05:56 PM 31/03/2020 AGENT_DISCONNECTED
3/31/2020 11:13:47 PM 31/03/2020 AGENT_RECONNECTED
3/31/2020 11:32:41 PM 31/03/2020 AGENT_DISCONNECTED
3/31/2020 11:34:27 PM 31/03/2020 AGENT_RECONNECTED
3/31/2020 11:35:55 PM 31/03/2020 AGENT_DISCONNECTED
3/31/2020 11:38:21 PM 31/03/2020 AGENT_RECONNECTED
3/31/2020 11:50:52 PM 31/03/2020 AGENT_DISCONNECTED
3/31/2020 1:15:02 PM  31/03/2020 AGENT_CONNECTED
3/31/2020 1:04:17 PM  31/03/2020 AGENT_DISCONNECTED
```

i need a help to get something complex done, the array is sorted with time, i need a logic which would start from the end of the array, find 1st instance of Event Type Agent_connected / Agent_reconnected, when its encountered check for the next item in the array see if the event type matches agent_disconnected, if it matches then -  check for the next item and see if the event type is Agent_Reconnnected / Agent_connected - if its so - then find the difference between the time for the agent_disconnected event and this Agent_reconnected / agent connected date, basically if any time a connected / reconnected event type is encountered in an the array after a disconnected event then we need to find a difference in time between these events.

an example - This array has 25 objects

$obj[24] = 3/31/2020 1:15:02 PM  31/03/2020 AGENT_CONNECTED
which is the first time an agent connect / disconnect is seen, if yes we see the next element

$obj[23] = 3/31/2020 11:50:52 PM 31/03/2020 AGENT_DISCONNECTED
we see that we see a disconnect event, which means we check the next element if its an agent connect / reconnect event

and we see $obj 22 satisfies this condition
$obj[22] = 3/31/2020 11:38:21 PM 31/03/2020 AGENT_RECONNECTED

and we get the diff as $obj[23].time - $obj[22].time, now we again go back and see the same condition for the remaining elements in the array - evaluate the above three conditions and find the difference in the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `$obj` is an array of custom objects with the properties in your post, you can do the following:

```
$obj | Sort {[datetime]$_.Time} | Foreach-Object {
    if ($_.'Event Type' -eq 'AGENT_DISCONNECTED') {
        $disc = [datetime]$_.Time
    } 
    else {
        $con = [datetime]$_.Time
        if ($disc) {
            "Agent connected at $($_.Time) after being disconnected for $($con - $disc)"
            $disc = $null
        }
    }
}
```

Perform a sort on the array while converting `Time` into a `[datetime]` object. Then perform a subtraction of the current (re)connected time object from the previous disconnected time object. The `$disc = $null` is only for when multiple (re)connects happen in a row. We are only subtracting the first (re)connect instance in that case.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't account for the 0th index being a 'Connect/Reconnect' -- if it is, it'll throw an exception due to there not being anything before it.

```
    $t = (@"
    Time, DateFormat, "Event Type"
    3/31/2020 11:59:35 PM,31/03/2020, AGENT_RECONNECTED
    3/31/2020 4:01:56 PM, 31/03/2020, AGENT_DISCONNECTED
    3/31/2020 4:14:19 PM, 31/03/2020, AGENT_CONNECTED
    3/31/2020 4:24:12 PM, 31/03/2020, AGENT_CONNECTED
    3/31/2020 4:30:31 PM, 31/03/2020, AGENT_DISCONNECTED
    3/31/2020 4:36:08 PM, 31/03/2020, AGENT_RECONNECTED
    3/31/2020 5:12:49 PM, 31/03/2020, AGENT_DISCONNECTED
    3/31/2020 6:25:39 PM, 31/03/2020, AGENT_RECONNECTED
    3/31/2020 7:09:08 PM, 31/03/2020, AGENT_DISCONNECTED
    3/31/2020 7:38:53 PM, 31/03/2020, AGENT_RECONNECTED
    3/31/2020 7:44:44 PM, 31/03/2020, AGENT_CONNECTED
    3/31/2020 8:23:48 PM, 31/03/2020, AGENT_DISCONNECTED
    3/31/2020 9:33:36 PM, 31/03/2020, AGENT_RECONNECTED
    3/31/2020 9:35:58 PM, 31/03/2020, AGENT_DISCONNECTED
    3/31/2020 10:46:54 PM,31/03/2020, AGENT_RECONNECTED
    3/31/2020 10:50:54 PM,31/03/2020, AGENT_DISCONNECTED
    3/31/2020 10:53:10 PM,31/03/2020, AGENT_RECONNECTED
    3/31/2020 11:05:56 PM,31/03/2020, AGENT_DISCONNECTED
    3/31/2020 11:13:47 PM,31/03/2020, AGENT_RECONNECTED
    3/31/2020 11:32:41 PM,31/03/2020, AGENT_DISCONNECTED
    3/31/2020 11:34:27 PM,31/03/2020, AGENT_RECONNECTED
    3/31/2020 11:35:55 PM,31/03/2020, AGENT_DISCONNECTED
    3/31/2020 11:38:21 PM,31/03/2020, AGENT_RECONNECTED
    3/31/2020 11:50:52 PM,31/03/2020, AGENT_DISCONNECTED
    3/31/2020 1:15:02 PM, 31/03/2020, AGENT_CONNECTED
    3/31/2020 1:04:17 PM, 31/03/2020, AGENT_DISCONNECTED
    "@) | ConvertFrom-Csv


    $o = for ($i = $t.Count; $i -gt 0; $i--) {
    if ($t[$i].'Event Type' -match 'AGENT_CONNECTED|AGENT_RECONNECTED') {
        if ($t[$i-1].'Event Type' -match 'AGENT_DISCONNECTED') {
            if ($t[$i-2].'Event Type' -match 'AGENT_CONNECTED|AGENT_RECONNECTED') {
                [pscustomobject]@{
                    'InitiatingIdx' = $i
                    'InitiatingDtm' = (Get-Date $t[$i].Time)
                    'DisconnectIdx' = $i-1
                    'DisconnectDtm' = (Get-Date $t[$i-1].Time)
                    'ReconnectIdx' = $i-2
                    'ReconnectDtm' = (Get-Date $t[$i-2].Time)
                    'DeltaMins'    = "{0:N2}" -f ((Get-Date $t[$i-1].Time) - (Get-Date $t[$i-2].Time)).TotalMinutes
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

$o | ft

    InitiatingIdx InitiatingDtm         DisconnectIdx DisconnectDtm         ReconnectIdx ReconnectDtm          DeltaMins
    ------------- -------------         ------------- -------------         ------------ ------------          ---------
               24 3/31/2020 1:15:02 PM             23 3/31/2020 11:50:52 PM           22 3/31/2020 11:38:21 PM 12.52    
               22 3/31/2020 11:38:21 PM            21 3/31/2020 11:35:55 PM           20 3/31/2020 11:34:27 PM 1.47     
               20 3/31/2020 11:34:27 PM            19 3/31/2020 11:32:41 PM           18 3/31/2020 11:13:47 PM 18.90    
               18 3/31/2020 11:13:47 PM            17 3/31/2020 11:05:56 PM           16 3/31/2020 10:53:10 PM 12.77    
               16 3/31/2020 10:53:10 PM            15 3/31/2020 10:50:54 PM           14 3/31/2020 10:46:54 PM 4.00     
               14 3/31/2020 10:46:54 PM            13 3/31/2020 9:35:58 PM            12 3/31/2020 9:33:36 PM  2.37     
               12 3/31/2020 9:33:36 PM             11 3/31/2020 8:23:48 PM            10 3/31/2020 7:44:44 PM  39.07    
                9 3/31/2020 7:38:53 PM              8 3/31/2020 7:09:08 PM             7 3/31/2020 6:25:39 PM  43.48    
                7 3/31/2020 6:25:39 PM              6 3/31/2020 5:12:49 PM             5 3/31/2020 4:36:08 PM  36.68    
                5 3/31/2020 4:36:08 PM              4 3/31/2020 4:30:31 PM             3 3/31/2020 4:24:12 PM  6.32     
                2 3/31/2020 4:14:19 PM              1 3/31/2020 4:01:56 PM             0 3/31/2020 11:59:35 PM -477.65
```